# How to add different prefix on invoice number based on payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, invoice

I am trying to find a solution to add different prefix on invoice number based on payment method.

Example:

- Invoice for order with credit card payment => CC as prefix
- Invoice for order with checkout money => CM as prefix

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on the below methods:

1. `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::_beforeSave`
2. `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\EntityAbstract::_beforeSave`

I think you have to override the above methods.

```
<?php
nameSpace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Model\EntityInterface;

class Order extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order
{
    protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $parentResult =  parent::_beforeSave($object);
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel $object */
            if ($object instanceof EntityInterface && $object->getEntityId() == null && $object->getIncrementId() != null) {
                $coreIncrement = $object->getIncrementId();
                $object->setIncrementId('Yourvaluee');
            }
        return $parentResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I need to add a prefix based on payment method. Can you elaborate more?